# How can I prove that the extremes of the interval of the solutions of this differential equation are equilibrium points?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to proof if $x:I\to \mathbb R$ a maximal regular solution of $x'=f(x)$, such that the image $x(I)\subset \mathbb R$ is bounded and $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is $C^1$, then the extremes $a$ and $b$ of x(I) are equilibrium points of $x'=f(x)$, i.e., $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

I need help to begin to solve this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if f(a) is not zero?

Comment: @MrSlunk Then $f(a)$ is regular, but I don't know which tool I have to use to solve the problem, maybe transversal sections?

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave it to you to formally prove it, but think about this;

Define the interval $I$ as $a<0<b$ (wlog).

Suppose $f(a)<0$, then the trajectory of $x(0)=a$ decreases and the image of $x(I)$ is unbounded.

Suppose $f(a)>0$, then trajectory stays inside the interval (at least initially) but it's not maximal as by continuity of $f$, there exists an $a'<a$ such that $f(a')=0$.

Same argument for the upper bound.

Comment: I didn't understand the second part when we suppose $f(a)\gt 0$. Why it's not maximal by continuity of $f$?

Comment: Because we can take an $a'<a$ such that the trajectory still stays inside the interval $a'<a<0<b$. Thus $(a,b)$ is not maximal. We can keep extending this interval until we reach $f(a')=0$.